# jquery removing element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have to remove certain elements without removing the entire div.For example 
Here,

```
<div>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <h1>Stack Overflow</h1>
    <div>This is a wonderful site</div>
</div>
```

I have to remove `<p>` and `<div>` tags without emptying whole div.Is there any usage of child selectors for removing like this in jquery.

Answer (score 9):

try this `$("div").children("p,div").remove();`

Using [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) you can select the element you wish to remove.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/tT97f/

Another method is using  child selector [`>`](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)  for example `$("div > p, div > div").remove();`

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/tT97f/1/

Comment: Is there is a way to  put only <h1> tag instead of removing like this

Comment: @Bhaskar: You could use `children(":not(h1)")`

Comment: @Bhaskar a way is what @Felix Kling wrote or a similar method `$("div").children().remove(":not('h1')");`

Comment: @Sotiris: I don't think putting the selector inside the `:not()` in quotes will work.